# Where do you find the documentation for the java plugin in gradle?

Tags: java, plugins, gradle

I am new to gradle.  I have found the tutorials and API JavaDocs for gradle.  One thing I am missing: when I say `apply plugin: java`, I know I've added functionality to the build script, but where is the documents or the source code for the Java plugin?  I know from the samples that I have `compile()` but what else?

Note: I'm happy to get a list of methods, but what I really want is the way to find this information for *any* plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gradle user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html) provides good documentation for standard plugins.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I thought when they started talking about writing your own plugins they weren't going to get into the standard one.  Didn't read far enough!